# DatagramPacket Constructor not found

Tags: java, udp

The following code produces "no suitable constructor found" error. I am unable to figure out a reason.

```
   try {
        Sock = new DatagramSocket();             
        InetAddress IP_add=InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.2");
        DatagramPacket PACKET=new DatagramPacket(buf,buf.length,IP_add,2000);

       } catch (Exception e) {}
```

Comment: Byte buf[]=new Byte[256]; is declared before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are e few options

1. Your buf instance is not array of byte, has to be `byte []`
2. You are using InetAddress not from package java.net

Recheck it, I think the first point will help you.

Comment: i also tried declaring it in the same block, still same thing